# 3ds challenge in an iframe within a modal

Tags: iframe, modal-dialog, checkout, 3d-secure

I have modal and on click on Purchase button in modal, if bank requires 3ds challenge, I want to show 3ds challenge inline in the modal. When 3ds challenge is shown everything else on modal becomes disabled.

The main issue is if 3ds challenge is shown as a modal and not inline that i am trying , it will be modal on top of my modal and will have accessibility issues.

Is it possible and acceptable to show 3ds challenge inline like that? or are there technical/security concerns?